# How to encode and decode using Prediction by Partial Matching method?

Tags: compression

For example, if I want to encode the word "programming", what would the result be? And I don't mean about the table, but the result, how to decode it back, and one more question, how the result of the encoding and the table is stored in a file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly know to which field this question applies to but there is something called Autoencoder in Machine Learning which is known to do things you are describing.

I don't know if this would be helpful or not but you should definitely check this out.

https://cs.stanford.edu/~quocle/tutorial2.pdf

Comment: Thanks but that is not what I meant. In Data Compression, there is a compression method called Prediction by Partial Matching, and almost every article I've read only show how the encoding works from the middle, not from the start and they only show how the encoding works, but not the decoding.